# Dynamic timer observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm facing with an issue related with how to create a dynamic "timer" observable.

Slightly I mean, I need to perform a function and according the value it returns (integer representing the number of seconds) I need to call the same function after these seconds have elapsed. So, I guess I need to re-schedule the observable according this another new value seconds.

I've tried to find something overthere but I',ve not been able to figure out what do I need to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Observable.Generate` with the `timeSelector` parameter. [Shameless plug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73702/61168).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Observable.Generate`. Try this example:

```
void Main()
{
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0, // initialState
            x => x < 10, //condition
            x => x + 1, //iterate
            x => x, //resultSelector
            x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(GetSeconds())) //timeSelector
        .Timestamp()
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Value} {x.Timestamp}"));
}

private double _seconds = 2.0;

public double GetSeconds()
{
    if (++_seconds > 5.0)
    {
        _seconds = 2.0;
    }
    return _seconds;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
0 2017/09/27 12:47:24 +00:00
1 2017/09/27 12:47:28 +00:00
2 2017/09/27 12:47:33 +00:00
3 2017/09/27 12:47:35 +00:00
4 2017/09/27 12:47:38 +00:00
5 2017/09/27 12:47:42 +00:00
6 2017/09/27 12:47:47 +00:00
7 2017/09/27 12:47:49 +00:00
8 2017/09/27 12:47:52 +00:00
9 2017/09/27 12:47:56 +00:00
```

The first result appears after `3.0` seconds (because of the initial `++seconds`) and the next value after `4.0` seconds as seen by the difference in the timestamp.

It stops after 10 values due to the `x => x < 10, //condition`.

Comment: Could you help me on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465215/reactive-refresh-accesstoken-using-observables). I need to emit refreshed oauth2 access tokens...