# Reactive: Refresh AccessToken using observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I don't quite figure out how to adapt [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445540/dynamic-timer-observable/46448362#46448362) in order to generate dynamic timer observables.

Concretly, I've two methods:

1. `GetAccessToken()`
2. `RefreshAccessToken()`

Both returns a `OAuth2AccessTokenResponse`:

```
public class OAuth2AccessTokenResponse
{
    private string tokenType;
    private string accessToken;
    private int expiresIn;
    private string refreshToken;
    private int refreshtokenExpiresIn;
}
```

So, I need to refresh the current accesstoken before `expiresIn` property value in seconds elapses.

I've tried to make my approach but I've not been able to get anything with sense:

```
this.accessTokenObservable = Observable
    .Generate(
        this.GetAccessToken(),
        resp => true, //?????
        resp => resp, //?????
        resp => resp, //?????
        resp => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.RefreshAccessToken().ExpiresIn) //?????
    );
```

Sequencially:

1. `response = this.GetAccessToken()`
2. Before `response.ExpiresIn` expires -> `response = this.RefreshAccessToken()`
3. Go to `2.`

`GetAccessToken` and `RefreshAccessToken` code:

```
internal OAuth2AccessTokenResponse GetAccessToken()
{
    return new OAuth2AccessTokenResponse() {ExpiresIn = new Math.Random().Next(3,11)};
}

internal OAuth2AccessTokenResponse RefreshAccessToken()
{
    return new OAuth2AccessTokenResponse() {ExpiresIn = new Math.Random().Next(3,11)};
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I need to be able to write code that works with `GetAccessToken` and `RefreshAccessToken` so I need all types.

Comment: Do you mean it would be right for you to have `GetAccessToken` and `RefreshAccessToken` code?

Comment: I mean I need to be able to copy, paste, and then compile your code so that I can then work with it. Right now when I copy what you've posted I get a load of errors. `IRestClient`, `RestSharp`, `this.settings`, `IRestRequest`, `AccessTokenRequest`, `IRestResponse<>`, `RefreshTokenRequest`, and `this.CheckResponse` are all undefined. You should make it easy for us to answer your question. A [mcve] would mean I'd have code that compiles.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to simplify `GetAccessToken` and `RefreshAccessToken` methods.

Comment: You are making it difficult to put an answer together. Your code still does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing a few compile errors, this seems to work for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var accessTokenObservable = Observable
        .Generate(
            this.GetAccessToken(),
            atr => true,
            atr => this.RefreshAccessToken(),
            atr => atr,
            atr => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(atr.ExpiresIn)
        );

    accessTokenObservable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ExpiresIn));
}

internal OAuth2AccessTokenResponse GetAccessToken()
{
    Console.WriteLine("!");
    return new OAuth2AccessTokenResponse() { ExpiresIn = rnd.Next(3, 11) };
}

internal OAuth2AccessTokenResponse RefreshAccessToken()
{
    Console.WriteLine("+");
    return new OAuth2AccessTokenResponse() { ExpiresIn = rnd.Next(3, 11) };
}

private Random rnd = new Random();

public class OAuth2AccessTokenResponse
{
    private string tokenType;
    private string accessToken;
    private int expiresIn;
    private string refreshToken;
    private int refreshtokenExpiresIn;

    public int ExpiresIn;
}
```

I get a result like this:

```
!
10
+
10
+
3
+
9
+
```